# Datatables JS - Conditional Formatting based on rank of data value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

I would like to format data within my table based on the rank of the value, using a kind of traffic light system, in the SCORE1 column in the table below for example, the score of 102 would be colored GREEN, the score of 89 would be YELLOW and the score of 7 would be RED.

```
NAME | SCORE1 | SCORE2 | SCORE3
--------------------------------
Ken  |   89   |   56   |   78
Sue  |   102  |   34   |   43
Dave |   7    |   200  |   12
```

My tables will contain between 3 and 30 rows, and I'd like to color the values a slightly different shade based on their ranking, from green to red.

Could this be done using some fancy Javascript/JQuery?

Comment: So something like a gradient of colours between red and green for each value in the column?

Comment: Yes, so the top ranked value would be bright green, 2nd ranked a slightly paler shade of green, going down though yellow into red. The hard part is determining the rank of each value.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, you can do it easily.

```
 var oTable = $('#countryTable').DataTable({ 
    'rowCallback': function(row, data, index){
    if(data[3]> 11.7){
        $(row).find('td:eq(3)').css('color', 'red');
    }
    if(data[2].toUpperCase() == 'EE'){
        $(row).find('td:eq(2)').css('color', 'blue');
    }
  }
});
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lr77dgmt/76/) to experiment.

Comment: Thats not quite doing what I need, I need the colour of the numbers to be assigned by rank, so if I specify that the highest score should be coloured green, then the highest score in each column would be green, the 2nd highest would be yellow, etc.

Comment: You can create rules for that. something like this: `var green = 70; var red = 30; if(data[index] > green){...} if(data[index] < red){...} `